# How to Block Spam Referral Traffic in Google Analytic?

Tags: google-analytics, googlebot

I have noticed so many spam referral traffic on my website on Google Analytic. I have tried to block them with the help of filters but it could not help.

I know there is also a way to block it with htaccess but is not any other way to block it in Google Analytic?

Looking forward for good solution

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

In reality, you can't block all the spam referral site.

Let me start with begin.

1. More and more people buy this type of script from blackhat market.
2. They host that kind of script on own domain.
3. It is not actual visit, it's just sent referral HTTP status to your site, and Google analytic count this.
4. If you block one domain, 10 others domain will come to your site.
5. They use attractive domain-name, so most of webmaster visit their sites.
6. When you check spam referral domain, they **inject advertising cookies** in your browser, while you click somewhere on their site or redirect to shopping site.
7. So whenever you buy something, they get commission, so this is the simplest game of their.

Solution:

1. Use Google analytics alternative like statcounter.com and histats.com
2. Use Google Webmaster Tools(Go to GWT > Search traffic > Search analytics) to check search result traffic.
3. Don't focus on Spam referral traffic :)